# Open MP with gsl_matrix is slower than sequential

Tags: openmp, gsl

I've created a simple c program using gsl(GNU Scienctific Library) and open mp. In this simple program, I want to test the execution time for sequential and parallel. Here is the program snippets, **main.c**.

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int n1=10000, n2=10000;
    gsl_matrix *A = gsl_matrix_alloc(n1, n2);

    int i,j;
    struct timeval tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;

    gettimeofday(&tv1, 0);

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++) 
    {
        for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
        {
            gsl_matrix_set(A, i, j, i*j*1000000);
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&tv2, 0);
    long elapsed = (tv2.tv_sec-tv1.tv_sec)*1000000 + tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec;

    printf("Sequential Duration:%ldms\n", elapsed); 

    gettimeofday(&tv3, 0);
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j)
    for(i=0; i<n1; i++) 
    {
        for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
        {
            gsl_matrix_set(A, i, j, i*j*1000000);
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&tv4, 0);
    elapsed = (tv4.tv_sec-tv3.tv_sec)*1000000 + tv4.tv_usec-tv3.tv_usec;
    printf("  Parallel Duration:%ldms\n", elapsed);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled the above code, using this command:

```
gcc -fopenmp main.c -o test -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Here is the program's result:

```
Sequential Duration:11980106ms
Parallel Duration:20624043ms
```

Why, the parallel part slower than the sequential part. How can I optimize this code? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it should be faster?

Answer (score 3):

as you have written it the `j` variable is shared between all threads so the threads are overwritting other threads state constantly, leading to them iterating values they have already covered.

You should always minimize the scope of variables when trying to parallelize with openmp. Either move the scope of j into the loop or mark it as private explicitly:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
```

also clock counts the processor time not the real time, you probably want to use `gettimeofday`

you matrix is too small to benefit much from parallelization, the threading overhead will dominate. Increase it to ~10000x10000 to start seeing something.

Comment: Hi @jtaylor, thanks for your answer. I've updated my question based on your suggestion and tried it. The sequential part still running faster than parallel part. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @jtaylor I cannot see the original version as the question has been edited already but loop counters are private in openmp hence that should not have been the issue.

Comment: @PetrH a nested loop counter is not part of the worksharing construct and thus not automatically private, if you use collapse maybe, but you'd have to look that up.

Comment: @jtaylor I see, I did not realize. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you do not know what the procedure `gsl_matrix_set` does with A. You do not know if it is thread safe. To change one element in that matrix you supply the whole matrix to the routine instead of only the indices of the element. This smells by false sharing (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189178/openmp-not-improving-runtime/25191906#25191906)).

I would try this instead

```
gsl_matrix_set(A[i][j],i*j*1000000);
```

If that does not work and what you are interested in is only the time difference between serial and parallel I would just do

```
A[i][j] = i*j*1000000
```

Answer (score -1):

In the thread part, try this:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i,j)
for(i=0; i<n1; i++) 
{
    for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
    {
        gsl_matrix_set(A, i, j, i*j*1000000);
    }
}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for(i=0; i<n1; i++) 
{
    for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
    {
        gsl_matrix_set(A, i, j, i*j*1000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first snippet is even worse as all threads will go over the whole loop not sharing the workload at all. The second snippet is the same as the OP has.

Comment: Taking jtaylor's comment into account the second snippet causes a race condition as explained by his answer since `j` won't be `private`.